# Can I enforce immutability of individual elements in a collection using plain JDK framework?

Tags: java, collections

I know there are wrapper methods like [`Collections#unmodifiableSet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#unmodifiableSet%28java.util.Set%29) and its other variations like [`Collections#unmodifiableMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#unmodifiableMap%28java.util.Map%29), [`Collections#unmodifiableList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#unmodifiableList%28java.util.List%29) etc which makes the collection immutable provided that the client only accesses the collection through the reference returned by these methods and not directly. But does it prevent the individual objects in the collections to be immutable? Can I achieve the same using standard JDK classes  and not apis like Google Guava?

Comment: How does Guava achieve your goal?

Comment: @Kent I am not saying Guava achieves my goal. I am basically looking for ways without Guava even if it achieves my goal . I hope the intent is clearer now.

Comment: Why not Guava though?  Widely used - thus tested by all those users, will continue to improve and get bug fixes without you needing to do anything, and you also get access to all the other stuff therein?

Comment: @JoeG Because I am not responsible for taking design decisions regarding adding the technology stack including third party jars for the project that i am working in.

Comment: Well I would consider recommending it (and I've never even been in a google building), but if you can't and haven't seen this SO article it might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5616306/defects-of-immutable-collections-of-guava?rq=1

Comment: @Geek: The answer to your question is no, there is no way, and never can be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you have to make yourself immutable versions of your classes.

Sample :

```
List< StringBuilder > l1 = new LinkedList< StringBuilder >();
l1.add( new StringBuilder()); // ok
List< StringBuilder > l2 = Collections.unmodiableList( l1 );
l2.get(0).append( "Hello" );  // ok, because StringBuilder, unlike String is mutable
l2.add( new StringBuilder()); // throws exception
```

Answer (score 0):

The only way I could think of making a class immutable that wasnt designed to be so is to wrap it in a Proxy - you could then access control any mutating methods:

ie.

```
MyClass {
  private int anInt;

  public void setInt(int a) {
      anInt = a;
  }
  public int getInt() {
      return anInt;
  }
  ...
```

and then

```
MyProxy {
  private MyClass myClass = ...;

  public int getInt() {
      return myClass.getInt();
  }
  ...
```

and so on.

You could also achieve the same thing through reflection (in the same way Spring wraps beans and you only generally interact with their proxies)

Not though that if a client got hold of the actual underlying class (MyClass in this example) then they would be able to mutate the internals.  Theres no real way to stop this directly, other than only ever exposing the "mutable" wrappers you let clients see

Answer (score 0):

If i understand your goal. You can use something like this

```
class Wraper<T>{
    List<T> list = new ArrayList<T>(); //Other Collection?
    T someObj = getYourInstance();
    public T get(int index) {
        T obj = list.get(index);
        if (obj.equals(someObj)){//should be overriden
           return createInstanceOf(obj);
        } else {
           return obj;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are asking for the equivalent of `const` in Java.  Which is not possible.  This has been requested by many users as an enhancement to Java (including myself) over the years.  It was closed and rejected by Sun.

https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=4211070

If you want to do this, you will have to build a mutability flag into your object (probably at construction time).  And then in every mutator method, check the mutability flag.  Perhaps you might be able to do something more "fancy" using a proxy library such as CGLIB, but it might be overly complicated for what you are trying to achieve.